# How to set a Visual Element to an absolute position on the screen in .net maui?

Tags: .net, controls, maui, .net-maui.shell

I'm trying to create an autocomplete control.

How it might look can be seen in the picture. At the same time, the hint block itself can be shown both above and below the input field (depending on the position of the block on the page and the opening/closing of the keyboard)

[image]

The control can be added to any screen, so binding to the Page's AbsoluteLayout should not be used. And the AbsoluteLayout is almost deprecated.

I understand how to do it in most "correctly" - create a Handler and in each of the handlers - separately for Android and separately for iOS, add a native view.
But this approach is too complicated for cross-platform development, since need to work with bindings separately, create separate handler parts for each platform, and so on.

The simplest and most convenient is to create a .net maui TableView with desired data and place it in the right place on the screen relative to the input field.

Can you please answer me how can I place an element with position relative to the screen on top of other UI elements using .net maui?

App is the shell app.

Comment: On top of other elements suggests an adorner. Did they fix the android position bug though?

Comment: @Andy to be honest i didn't think that placing TableView in Adorner is a good idea, but i didn't have strong opinion about that. Anyway, i'm sorry but i still didn't deal with android on maui, just try to make iOS works first.

Comment: In Maui, layout is always controlled by some Layout class, and its LayoutManager. If you want something to be addable to ANY page, you'll have to create a top-level layout that ALL pages are based on. You could use a [ContentPresenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.contentpresenter?view=net-maui-7.0), or a [Control template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate?view=net-maui-7.0). Sorry, I'm vague on details; perhaps someone else can say more.

Comment: `AbsoluteLayout` and `RelativeLayout` have been moved to the Compatibility namespace. You can try to use Grid layout. For more information, you can refer to Announcing .NET MAUI Preview 7 by official blog.